# Using an image as fallback when Gists are not loading

Tags: html, css, github, jekyll, gist

I am using jekyll for blogging and almost all of my posts are related to coding and due to that lot of my posts contain embedded gists as below

`{% gist gist_id %}`

Sometimes when the gists don't load (it has happened quite often) there is nothing that shows up, the content is just blank.This is quite awkward and it leaves readers confused,previously I was using [Gist embed](https://github.com/blairvanderhoof/gist-embed), but since jekyll has native support I stopped using them,but they gave good error messages such as failed loading gist which although not really friendly, gave some idea on what went wrong.

Is there some script that I can put in like [this one](http://blackhillswebworks.com/2013/08/06/use-a-background-image-as-a-fallback-when-embedded-gists-dont-appear/) so that it makes more sense to the viewers

Answer (score 0):

Storing content outside of your site and replacing text by image is an accessibility and SEO anti pattern.

Using [Jekyll `{% highlight %}` tag](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#code-snippet-highlighting) is the best way to keep your content in your site and avoid relying on *solar powered* external services.